# Vuetify data table get selected item

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have a v-data-table that has Show-select,
I want to get the data of what items I selected, at least alert the first column value upon check
. Im searching everywhere. i cant find answer to my problem.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :value="selected"
      @input="enterSelect($event)"
      :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      show-select
      class="elevation-1"
    >
    </v-data-table>
    <v-dialog>
      <v-card>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods: {
    enterSelect(values) {
      if (values.length == this.itemsPerPage) {
        alert('selected all')
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      selected: [],
      itemsPerPage: 10,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

https://codepen.io/CodingDeer/pen/QWLyaog?editors=1010

this is just an example of what I recently found (code not mine),
this code can detect if all checkbox selected

Comment: I want to get the value of the row selected. at least i get the first column or any part of the row selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you want to get the names of the rows, here's how to get them.

```js
methods: {
  enterSelect(values) {
      var names = values.map(function(value){ return value.name })
      console.log(names)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `v-model` instead of `:value` to allow modification of `selected` variable when you try to select some items. Then check the `this.selected`'s length inside the `enterSelect` function.

```html
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  @input="enterSelect()"
  ...
>...</v-data-table>
```

```js
methods: {
  enterSelect() {

    console.log(this.selected.map(e => e.name));  // logs all the selected items.

    if (this.selected.length == this.itemsPerPage) {
      alert('selected all')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but how can i get the value of what I specifically check? i least the name of it.

Comment: Similar to the accepted answer, use Array.map() to the `selected` variable. (e.g. `console.log(this.selected.map(e => e.name))`)